# How to route URL properly if query string has an array?

Tags: typo3-extensions, typo3-11.x

I use TYPO3 V11.5.x. At the moment the url looks like:

```
jobs/aa=1?selectTopic[0]=50&selectTopic[1]=46&selectTopic[2]=48&cHash=e064f3d7acb07445927237eff65b0a45
```

The parameter selectTopic[x] comes from an array which is passed to the Fluid-ViewHelper f:link.page:

```
<f:link.page pageUid="11" additionalParams="{selectTopic:activity.topic-jcid,isactivityarea:1}" class="aa-item">
```

Right now I use in config.yaml:

```
routeEnhancers:
  IsActivityArea:
    type: Simple
    limitToPages:
      - 11
    routePath: '/aa={isaa}'
    requirements:
      isaa: '[0-1]'
    _arguments:
      isaa: 'isactivityarea'
  ActivityAreaTopics:
    type: Simple
    limitToPages:
      - 11
    routePath: '/topic={topic-id}'
    requirements:
      topic-id: '[0-9]{1,4}'
    _arguments:
      topic-id: 'selectTopic[0]'
```

The first part "IsActivityArea" works as expected. But the second part in "ActivityAreaTopics" does not bring a good result. How can you achieve that the array is also displayed correctly? What would be best practice with the usual on-board tools? Or do I have to write a custom mapper?

Thanks in advance for your tips and help.
Best regards, Daniel